# Angucomplete-alt in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angucomplete-alt in Angular1 js, selected-object callback is giving undefined not always but once in 15-20 attempts. when getting selected value in callback ,sometime it is returning object and sometime it is undefined. It is happening when i click on item. sometime on click on item it is giving object in selected of callback sometime undefned

Comment: Post your code. Since its giving error only sometimes, there's something external to the component. The input you are providing does has a big impact here, so check if its valid input all the times

Comment: div(id='{{sft._id}}_{{eventAcc._id}}_{{week}}_{{tmsl}}_{{sft.startShiftTime}}_{{sft.endshiftTime}}', angucomplete-alt='', placeholder='Align User', pause = '100', auto-match='auto-match', maxlength='50', selected-object='selectedUser', remote-api-handler='yesMaybeEmployee', title-field='fullname', minlength='1', input-class='form-control form-control-small', match-class='highlight', focus-in='focusIn()', focus-out='focusOut()', initial-value='selectedEmpArr[sft._id]')

Comment: In My Angular controller : 

$scope.selectedUser = function(selected){
   --> here in selected sometime i got object and rare got undefined.

$scope.yesMaybeEmployee = function (str, timeoutPromise) {
....
 return $timeout(function () {
     return {"data": matches};
 }, 1000);

}